# Increasing frequency of review audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits

While reviewing suggested edits during the last week or so, I noticed many weird spammy edits. I then realized by looking at my history that it was an audit.

I have been seeing those audits nearly every day for the past week, way more than I used to notice them.

Is it normal that they are so frequent? Or am I being targeted for some reason? Not that I take it too personally, but if I am doing something wrong in the reviews, I would like to know how I can improve.

Comment: They should be regular enough that people will be careful with them - and that people who regularly fail them might actually end up getting review-banned. I would expect them to come up at least once a day for someone mildly active at reviewing, as a result. But I don't know the frequencies; I suspect that is at least mildly-protected info.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I understand. But the suggested edit audits are quite obvious if you take 2 seconds to read it, I almost never noticed them before. I had nearly 400 reviews already. That's why I was not sure.

Comment: I think it's totally random - I would guess the chance to get audit is 1 to 20, so if you use all 20 reviews every day then yes you're likely to bump into at least one audit every day.

Comment: If you take two seconds to read the suggestion, you've already shown more care than those the audits are meant for.

Comment: I think the frequency of these is being tweaked. There were a couple of users who were getting audits much less frequently than they should have been, so I heard this was being worked on. Maybe it has now swung hard in the other direction.

Comment: @BradLarson Interesting. It makes sense, maybe I was not audited enough before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, we did increase the frequency a bit. It's still random chance whether any given review will be an audit or not, but there's a much lower "no audits" period after you've been audited.

As [Sha Wiz Dow Ard suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170797/increasing-frequency-of-review-audits#comment505402_170797), most active reviewers should see at least one review audit per day.

Answer (score 2):

The point it to check your attention. As stated in the comments, if you actually read the audit, you'll pass. It doesn't matter how often it is *for you*.

People who fail consecutive audits will be suspended from reviewing. And that's the point really, to hinder those who blindly review just for the sake of the badge (or trolling, or whatever other reason).

If you *do* pay attention, you shouldn't have a problem. The current system is still under heavy observation, and is being tweaked to find that golden spot where we can be transparent towards real reviewers, and also remove the "blind" ones.

#### TL;DR

Don't worry about it. It's normal.